# Avoid circular reference with decorator that takes argument from another script

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have two files...

`utils.py`:

```
def decorator(connection):
    def _decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'Connected to {connection}:')
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return _decorator

@decorator(db)
def do_thing(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

`run.py`:

```
from utils import do_thing 

db = 'db_connection'
do_thing('A', 'B', 'C')
```

`utils.py` contains a decorator that connects to a database.

The problem: `run.py` imports `utils.py`, but `utils.do_thing` is decorated with an argument I ultimately want to pass in from `run.py`.

How can I adjust things to A) make this work and B) avoid circular referencing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a third file, e.g. `shared.py`, in which you define `db`.
Then you can import that from both files:

shared.py:

```
# prepare db stuff here
db = …
```

utils.py:

```
from shared import db
def decorator():
    …
@decorator(db)
def do_thing(*args):
    …
```

run.py:

```
from utils import do_thing
do_thing(…)
```

Comment: A good idea! But I think I want to keep it to two because I want the user to just have to define things in one file (db connection might be different)

Comment: Then you could try out importing the complete module:

    import run
    run.db

and 

    import utils
    utils.do_thing

This improves python's ability to solve circular dependencies.